# Mechanize Firefox synchronize option is not working

Tags: perl, www-mechanize-firefox

I am trying to use Mechanize::Firefox but it is hanging after the first click.  When you pass in the object to click it does not seem to be honoring the synchronize flag.
Any ideas?  Is this a bug or am I just doing it wrong?

```
my @objects = $mech->selector(‘input’);
foreach my $object (@objects){
                $mech->click($object,{synchronize => 0});
                select(undef,undef,undef,2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The following code works.

```
my @objects = $mech->selector(‘input’);
foreach my $object (@objects){
                $mech->click({dom=>$object,synchronize => 0});
                select(undef,undef,undef,2);
}
```